# Preserve selectizeInput selection in text box after actionButton is used

Tags: r, input, shiny

Default ordering is: Item1, Item2, Item3. If I select a new order and click Update, my selection disappears, but the output table is correct.

[image]

How do I preserve my selection so that it shows up like so even after Update is clicked?

[image]

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI({
    fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(uiOutput("selection"),
                     actionButton('update',"Update")),
        mainPanel(
          tableOutput('ordered')
        )
      )
    )
  }),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    values <- reactiveValues(x = c('Item1','Item2','Item3'))
    
    output$selection <- renderUI({
      selectizeInput('neworder',
                     'Select order:',
                     choices = values$x,
                     selected = preserve$selection,
                     multiple = TRUE,
                     options = list(plugins = list('remove_button', 'drag_drop')))
    })
    
    output$ordered <- renderTable(
      values$x
    )
    
    preserve <- reactiveValues(selection = character())
    
    observeEvent(input$neworder,{
      if (!all(preserve$selection %in% input$neworder)) {
        preserve$selection = input$neworder
      }
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$update,{
      id <- values$x %in% input$neworder
      values$x <- c(input$neworder, values$x[!id])
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isolate()` to avoid unwanted update:

```
  selectizeInput('neworder',
                 'Select order:',
                 choices = isolate(values$x),
                 selected = preserve$selection,
                 multiple = TRUE,
                 options = list(plugins = list('remove_button', 'drag_drop')))
```